# How to require assets when using Webpack and Express.js without a client side framework?

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, webpack-4

I am writing a standard express.js application without any client-side framework like React, Vue or Angular. The HTML-Templates get rendered from the server like this:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index') // template engine ejs
})

app.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.render('about') // template engine ejs
})
```

I'm using Webpack to build my static assets like javascript files, css files and images.

**Question:** how can I use assets in my HTML template if the asset files have a hash code included in their name. For example `sample.a23ijafj.jpg`.

Since the hash codes always change when the file gets edited I can't just use the generated filename:

```
<img src="sample.a23ijafj.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this Webpack plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin

With this, you can create HTML template to generate together with your other resources.
I have not actually used it myself, but it seems it has enough documentation to solve your problem.